# Propel: No connection available for myproject database

Tags: php, propel

I'm getting an error while doing

```
$ ./propel model:build --verbose
Processing: schema.xml
  1 tables processed successfully
1 tables found in 1 schema files.
Generating PHP files...
Datamodel: ./schema.xml
 - Database: myproject
  + Table: resource
        -> (unchanged) /Base/Resource.php
        -> (unchanged) /Map/ResourceTableMap.php
        -> (unchanged) /Base/ResourceQuery.php
        -> (exists) Resource.php
        -> (exists) ResourceQuery.php
                (no change)
Object model generation complete - All files already up to date
$ ./propel sql:build --verbose
Processing: schema.xml
  1 tables processed successfully
1 tables found in 1 schema files.
$ ./propel sql:insert --verbose
No connection available for myproject database
$
```

The output is:

`No connection available for myproject database`

Here are my 3 files of interest:

[build.properties](http://pastebin.com/2QRXsUuM)

[runtime-conf.xml](http://pastebin.com/FDbcBYyd)

[schema.xml](http://pastebin.com/h0saV9Va)

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing these in your build.properties:

```
propel.runtime.conf.file   = runtime-conf.xml
propel.buildtime.conf.file = buildtime-conf.xml
```

You **buildtime-conf.xml** is very similar to your **runtime-conf.xml**, so you can just duplicate, rename and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Where is it mentioned in the documentation? apart from http://propelorm.org/reference/buildtime-configuration as a small tip?

Comment: You will find it [here](http://propelorm.org/reference/buildtime-configuration#directories-and-filenames)

Comment: I saw that. It describes the buildtime config filename to be used and mentions that I need a buildtime-conf.xml if I'm using more than one database. I'm using just one. I'm just saying it's a bit unclear from the documentation.

Comment: It is somewhat self-descriptive... The buildtime-conf is used when you "build" your classes, i.e. during migrations/schema changes, and the runtime-conf if for when you're running your app, a conf/{project}-conf.php is generated from the runtime-conf.xml.  It's just one of those things that you deal with once, get it right and then forget about it.